Why shouldn't I omit the connectedCallback method by using Promise.resolve().then() to delay firing theFlowAttributeChangeEvent inside the set method?
I do not quite understand the consequence of "omit the connectedCallback method by using
Promise.resolve().then(...) to delay firing theFlowAttributeChangeEvent inside the set method".
Can anyone help me understand the meaning of "Consequently, the flow runtime always overrides preserved values and overrules the setting for revisited value"?
Examples would be very helpful.
Best Practices for Reactivity in Screen Flows 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-best-practices-reactivity.html

4.Don't omit the connectedCallback method by using
Promise.resolve().then(...) to delay firing the
FlowAttributeChangeEvent inside the set method. Delaying the
FlowAttributeChangeEvent ensures that the component is in the DOM when
the flow first calls the set method. However, the delay also means
that the component fires the event after the flow initializes the
screen. Consequently, the flow runtime always overrides preserved
values and overrules the setting for revisited value.
set stringToCount(newStringToCount) {
   this._stringToCount = newStringToCount;
   const lengthChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('stringLength', this._stringToCount.length);
   // This code overwrites preserved values. Don't do this.
   Promise.resolve().then(() => {
     this.dispatchEvent(lengthChangeEvent);
   });
 }


